# Prioridad en sentencias con punteros en C

Tags: c, punteros

Tenia una duda de preferencias y operadores sobre los punteros.

Primero, lo que creo que es correcto:

- `*a.b` es lo mismo que `*(a.b)`
- `(*a).b` es lo mismo que `a->b`
- `*a.b` **no** es `(*a).b`

Repito, en principio esto está bien, pero puedo estar equivocado.

Ahora, el problema de la preferencia:

- ¿`*a->b` es `*((*a).b)`?
- ¿`*a.b->c` es `*((*(a.b)).c)`? (lo último que he dicho en teoría es igual a `*(*a.b).c`)
- ¿`*(a.b)->c` es lo mismo que la sentencia de arriba?

Resumiendo, cual es su preferencia? (en el caso de tener '.', '->', paréntesis...)

Comment: Por favor, limítate a **1** cuestión por pregunta. Aparte de eso, cada una de tus cuestiones se comprueba **con 2 líneas de código**. ¿ Lo has intentado ?

Comment: He probado muchas, y en teoría todo lo que digo es cierto. Es cierto que pregunto varias cosas, pero lo que quiero saber es la preferencia de C frente a estos operadores.

Comment: Supongo que por *preferencia* te refieres a *la prioridad* de cada uno de ellos: en [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) lo tienes todo.

Comment: Ya que estamos ... ¿ Te has pasado por [la ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para ver como funciona el sitio ? Especificamente, por [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ¿Cual es tu duda especifica? ¿Quieres saber como funcionan esas sentencias?

Comment: Quiero la conversión de eso a paréntesis, en base a lo que C prioriza.